# Custom Compose Arrangement to add extra spacing at beginning and end of a LazyRow/LazyColumn

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-list

How can I create a custom `Arrangement` for `LazyRow` to add additional spacing at beginning and end, but have even spacing in between?

Start|< more space> Item 1  Item 2  Last Item |End

```kotlin
object CustomArrangement : Arrangement.Horizontal {
  override fun Density.arrange(
    totalSize: Int,
    sizes: IntArray,
    layoutDirection: LayoutDirection,
    outPositions: IntArray
  ) {

  }
}
```

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists#custom-arrangements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not the answer to your question, but you can achieve the same adding a header and footer items, or using a horizontal `PaddingValues`.

A simple `LazyRow`:

```
LazyRow(
    horizontalArrangement =   Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 50.dp),
    modifier= Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
) {

    items(itemsList) {
        Text("Item is $it")
    }
}
```

or something like:

```
LazyRow(
    horizontalArrangement =   Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
    modifier= Modifier.fillMaxSize()
) {
    //Header
    item(){
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(40.dp))
    }
    items(itemsList) {
        Text("Item is $it")
    }
    //Footer
    item(){
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(40.dp))
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can get the effect you're looking for with one of the paramenters for LazyRow: contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = "your_value")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).